# Take a Json object from three webpages and write that in a file?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write a python script that will take a json object from a web page and write it to a flat file. There are ten lines in the flat file and three web pages. I have come to this code with the help of various online resources:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import simplejson

r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
c = r.content
j = simplejson.loads(c)

for item in j:
    print item['repository']['name']
```

This code returns json objects from the github timeline events. The returned json objects are parsed and printed as a dictionary. I want to know is this a good way or is there a better way to do this?

Also, is there a way to send the json object to a python script that will update the flat file with the inputs from a webpage?

P.S  Flat files are data files that contain records with no structured relationships. A normal .txt file with data.

Comment: Have you considered YAML file? What values do you want to store?

Comment: why don't you update the flat file in the same script that sends requests to github? There are many IPC methods if you want to send data to another program. You need be more specific.

Comment: I will update the flat file in this same script. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` can decode json text for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests

r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
for item in r.json or []:
    print item['repository']['name']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I write the objects in the file?

Comment: @user1687755: do you want to save 'timeline.json' or a some part of it to a local file? `urllib.urlretrieve()` does the former, you could use `json.dump()` for the latter.

Comment: I want to save some part of it..I want to save the printed objects 'repository' and 'name' in the file.